# Redux return total price in cart

Tags: redux, react-redux

Hi my redux app currently adds cart items, but I would like to function to count the total price.

**How can I do this in redux?**

Currently my **Reducer** looks like this.

```
const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
        // console.log('CarItems.JS', action.payload)
            if (state.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id)) {
                // increase qty if item already exists in cart
                return state.map(cartItem => (cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty + 1 } : cartItem));
            }
            return [...state, { ...action.payload, qty: 1 }]; // else add the new item to cart

        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            return state
                .map(cartItem => (cartItem.id === action.payload.id ? { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty - 1 } : cartItem))
                .filter(cartItem => cartItem.qty > 0);
    }
    return state
} 

export default cartItems
```

> Solution

Calculate total sum and return it.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let totalPrice = 0;
    state.map((item) => { 
      totalPrice += item.price * item.qty;
    });
    return {
        cartItems: state,
        totalPrice : totalPrice
    }
}
```

call upon it in the view

```
<Text style={styles.total}>Totaal: € {this.props.totalPrice}</Text>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to create a selector for this which you can use from `mapStateToProps`.

It will look something like

```
function getTotalCost (state) {
  return state.reduce((result, item) => item.qty * item.price + result, 0); 
}
```

In your component..
(I'm not sure how your app or state is structured so this will likely need some tweaking)

```
import { getTotalCost } from "./items/selectors";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    totalCost: getTotalCost(state.items)
  }
}

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { totalCost } = this props;
    ...
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Component)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate this a bit more?

Comment: that's nonsensical. a selector is just a function, it doesn't have anything to do with react-redux. `getTotalCost` takes the items list as per your example which is an array which you can call reduce on.

Comment: elaborated in answer. For more info you can find lots of posts describing selector usage via https://www.google.com/search?q=redux+selectors